# Is there ever a reason to have parentheses within an @Webservice(.....) annotation in Java EE?

Tags: java, regex, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am building some static analysis tools to help manage the architecture of a large project. For this I am doing a couple of regexes to parse information from Java files. One of these regexes is used to scan for an @WebService(... ) annotation.

I was wondering if there is a situation possible where there are parentheses in an @WebService annotation (withhelding the ones at the start and end, and any in String literals or comments). 
So the ones in

```
@WebService(serviceName="bla()" /* bla() */);
```

are ok; whereas the ones in

```
@WebService( ... ( ... ) ...);
```

are not.

Does the latter ever occur?

Comment: No it doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there can be parenthesis even outside of string literals.

In general, annotations can have constant expressions as arguments, that evaluate to a primitive, String, Class, Enum, Annotation or Array. String literals, annotations parameters and expressions can contain parenthesis. The following declaration is valid:

```
@WebService(serviceName="bla()" + ("bla") + (2 * 3));
```

The annotation could also contain comments that include parenthesis:

```
@WebService(serviceName="bla()" /* ( ) */); 

@WebService( // ( )
   serviceName="bla()");
```

Comment: Your answer is technically correct. I'm just wondering when the first example will ever occur :-)

Comment: @Kristof Probably never :) I can't think of any good reason why anyone would add parenthesis there, except maybe for calculating numerical values.